# How to fill a datagridview with objects of a class

Tags: vb.net

Okay so I think I've confused myself. I'm working on a class inventory database.  My plan is to have a person enter their information and a book's info into the textboxes, and I want that informationan to be placed into the lstbox (basically saying who is now renting this book). I also have a Datagridview where I want my txtfile to open up in and display the books, but only the objects that are in my txtfile (Title, Author, ISBN, YearPublishished). I tried to do it with a query but it doesn't seem to be working.

I have a few errors that I need help with

1. When I start the application and click on display books. My OFD opens and I click the txtfile I need, but it doesnt display to my DataGridView properly. IT only shows numbers going down the columns.
2. We had to use objects of classes, and I just want to know if Im using them correctly. This is my first time doing this so any help would be appreciated.
3. I've attached a picture of my Application

Okay so this what I have so far:

```
Public Class Library


Implements IComparable


    'Private Instance Variables - Always declared as Private
    Private m_Title As String
    Private m_Author As String
    Private m_ISBN As String
    Private m_YearPublished As Date
    Private m_DateRented As Date    'use maskedtxtbox for dates and phone number
    Private m_DueDate As Date
    Private m_Name As String
    Private m_Email As String
    Private m_PhoneNumber As String

    Private Shared LibraryCount As Integer

    'Property Blocks for each Private Instance Variable
    Public Property Title() As String
        Get
            Return m_Title
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            m_Title = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property Author() As String
        Get
            Return m_Author
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            m_Author = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property ISBN As String
        Get
            Return m_ISBN
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            m_ISBN = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Public Property YearPublished As Date
        Get
            Return m_YearPublished
        End Get
        Set(value As Date)
            m_YearPublished = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Public Property DateRented As Date
        Get
            Return m_DateRented
        End Get
        Set(value As Date)
            m_DateRented = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property DueDate As Date
        Get
            Return m_DueDate
        End Get
        Set(value As Date)
            m_DueDate = value
        End Set
    End Property



    Public Property Name As String
        Get
            Return m_Name
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            m_Name = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property Email As String
        Get
            Return m_Email
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            m_Email = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property PhoneNumber As String
        Get
            Return m_PhoneNumber
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            m_PhoneNumber = value
        End Set
    End Property


    Public Sub New()
        m_Title = ("")
        m_Author = ""
        m_ISBN = ""
        m_DateRented = ""
        m_DueDate = ""
        m_Name = ""
        m_Email = ""
        m_PhoneNumber = 0
        LibraryCount += 1
    End Sub

    'Overloaded /Parameterized Constructors

    Public Sub New(ByVal p_Title As String, ByVal p_Author As String, ByVal p_ISBN As String, ByVal p_YearPublished As Date,
               ByVal p_DateRented As Date, ByVal p_DueDate As Date, ByVal p_Name As String, ByVal p_Email As String, ByVal p_PhoneNumber As String)
        m_Title = p_Title
        m_Author = p_Author
        m_ISBN = p_ISBN
        m_YearPublished = p_YearPublished
        m_DateRented = p_DateRented
        m_DueDate = p_DueDate
        m_Name = p_Name
        m_Email = p_Email
        m_PhoneNumber = p_PhoneNumber
        LibraryCount += 1
    End Sub


    'QUESTION? How would I calculate when the books is due
    '  Public Function CalcDueDate() As String     'person gets charged if they are late returning the book    

    ' If m_DateRented.Date > m_DueDate.Date Then
    'm_DueDate = m_DateRented + 10
    'MessageBox.Show("You will be charged with a late of .50 cents")
    'End If
    'End Function

    Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
        Return "The user rented a book on" & DateRented & " it will be due on" & DueDate
    End Function

    Public Function CalcDueDate(ByVal p_DueDate As Date) As Date

        Return p_DueDate
    End Function
    Public Function CompareTo(obj As Object) As Integer Implements IComparable.CompareTo

        Throw New NotImplementedException()
        Return m_YearPublished.CompareTo(CType(obj, Library).m_YearPublished)

    End Function

    Public Overrides Function Equals(obj As Object) As Boolean
        'create a library object from the paramer - check to see if it exist
        Dim libraryobj As Library = TryCast(obj, Library)
        If libraryobj Is Nothing Then
            Return False
        Else
            'code for the comparison based on m_yearpublished
            Return m_YearPublished.Equals(libraryobj.m_YearPublished)
        End If
    End Function


End Class

 End Class





Public Class Project1Data

'create counter variable for the array
Dim counter As Integer = 0
'create an array of objects
Private books(12) As Library
'Collection List
Dim mybooklist As New List(Of Library)


Dim abook As Library



Private Sub btnDisplayBooks_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnDisplayBooks.Click

    Dim textfile As String
    OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog()
    textfile = OpenFileDialog1.FileName
    DGVbooks.DataSource = IO.File.ReadAllLines("LibraryDatabase")

End Sub

Public Sub Data()

End Sub
Private Sub btnAdd_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnAdd.Click
    'The Btn_Add method creates a Renter and book and adds it to the collectio

    'validate input data
    If ValidateData() = -1 Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

    'use valid input to create an object of the class by calling overloaded constructor
    Dim bookk As New Library(txtbooktitle.Text, txtbookauthor.Text, txtISBN.Text, CDate(txtyearpublished.Text),
                            CDate(txtdaterented.Text), CDate(txtduedate.Text), txtname.Text, txtemail.Text, (txtphonenunber.Text))


    'error check that the array is not full
    If counter >= books.Length Then
        ReDim Preserve books(counter + 1)
    End If

    'add book to the array
    books(counter) = bookk
    'add book to the list
    mybooklist.Add(bookk)

    'increment counter
    counter = counter + 1

    'Notify user that the rental has been recorder
    MessageBox.Show("Rental recorded")

    lstbooksoutput.DataSource = Nothing
    lstbooksoutput.DataSource = books

End Sub

Private Sub Project1Data_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim lines() As String = IO.File.ReadAllLines("LibraryDatabase")


    'In the DGV I just want to display the title, author, isbn, and year published
    ' In the lstbox the user name, email, and phone number will be displayed
    'When a user enters a new book it adds itself to the DGV


    Dim query = From abook In books
                Select abook.Title, abook.Author, abook.ISBN, abook.YearPublished
                Order By abook.YearPublished Ascending
    DGVbooks.DataSource = query.ToList()
```

Okay here is where I created an objectof the class using an overload constructor, and I thought I sent it it to the datagridview but its not showing.

```
    'Populate a list with Library objects

    With mybooklist
        .Add(New Library("Innoncent Injustice(A Chance Reddick Thriller Book 1), David Archer,B07D6442LM", 2018))
        .Add(New Library("A Breath Of Witchy Air(A Wicked Witches Of the Midwest Mystery), Amanda M Lee, B07CRLRGXH", 2018))
        .Add(New Library("Booke Of the Hidden, Jeri Westerson, 978 - 1635760507", 2017))
        .Add(New Library("Wolves Of Wisteria(Wisteria Witches Mystery), Angela Pepper,978-1719549591", 2018))
        .Add(New Library("Soul Render(Soul Stones Book 1), TL Branson,978-1980871392", 2018))
        .Add(New Library("A Thrift Shop Murder(Cats And Ghosts And Avocado Toasts Book 1), Stanford Pritchard,978-1773480114", 2018))
        .Add(New Library("Cathadeus, Jeff J Peters,B077ZNHY7T", 2017))
        .Add(New Library("Clockwork Alchemist (Thief's Apprenctice Series Book 1), Sara C. Roethle,B01MG26KNA", 2016))
        .Add(New Library("Air Awakens Series, Elise Kova,B01N4A2TK5", 2016))
        .Add(New Library("Keeper of the Dragons The Prince Returns (Keeper of Dragons Book 1), J.A Cullican,B01FYL5BD0", 2016))
        .Add(New Library("Nightblade A Book of UnderRealm, Garrett Robinson,978-1941076309", 2014))
        .Add(New Library("Crazy Rich Asians, Kevin Kwan,B00AP2VQEM", 2013))
        .Add(New Library("Poison Princess (The Arcana Chronicles Book 1), Kresley Cole,978-1442436640", 2012))

    End With

    DGVbooks.DataSource = query.ToList
        DGVbooks.Columns("Title").HeaderText = "Title"
        DGVbooks.Columns("Author").HeaderText = "Author"
        DGVbooks.Columns("ISBN").HeaderText = "ISBN"
        DGVbooks.Columns("Year Publsihed").HeaderText = "Year Published"

        DGVbooks.DataSource = mybooklist
End Sub

Function ValidateData() As Integer
    'This validates the data in all of the textboxes
    'Invalid data returns a -1, else 1
    If txtbooktitle.Text = "" Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter a Book Title")
        Return -1
    ElseIf txtbookauthor.Text = "" Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter a Book Title")
        Return -1
    ElseIf txtdaterented.Text = "" Or IsNumeric(txtdaterented.Text) = False Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter a valid date")
        Return -1
    ElseIf txtduedate.Text = "" Or IsNumeric(txtduedate.Text) = False Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter a valid date")
        Return -1
    ElseIf txtyearpublished.Text = "" Or IsNumeric(txtyearpublished.Text) = False Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter a valid date")
        Return -1
    ElseIf txtname.Text = "" Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter a name")
        Return -1
    ElseIf txtemail.Text = "" Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter a valid email")
        Return -1
    ElseIf txtphonenunber.Text = "" Or IsNumeric(txtphonenunber.Text) = False Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter a valid phone number")
        Return -1
    Else
        Return 1
    End If

End Function




Private Sub lstbooksoutput_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles lstbooksoutput.SelectedIndexChanged
    If lstbooksoutput.SelectedIndex > -1 Then
        Dim intbook As Integer = lstbooksoutput.SelectedIndex
        'get information for that user in the array
        MessageBox.Show(books(intbook).Name & "  has rented" & books(intbook).Title & ".  The book will be due on " & books(intbook).DueDate)

    End If
End Sub


Private Sub btnClear_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnClear.Click
    'clear the textboxes
    txtbooktitle.Clear()
    txtbookauthor.Clear()
    txtISBN.Clear()
    txtdaterented.Clear()
    txtduedate.Clear()
    txtyearpublished.Clear()
    txtname.Clear()
    txtemail.Clear()
    txtphonenunber.Clear()

    'reset focus to title box
    txtbooktitle.Focus()
End Sub
```

End Class

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PTqL7.png)

Comment: Your question is probably too broad for Stack Overflow, but welcome. Go back to where you signed up and learn what a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example is. If you can tell what version of Visual Studio you are using, I might be able to shed a little light.

Comment: `With mybooklist` When you create new library objects you are trying to call a custom constructor. I know you think you are passing in all the parameters but you are really only passing 2. From the beginning of the quotation mark to the ending quotation is one string. The compiler doesn't care what you put in the string, only that it is one string. The second parameter is a number type. Your custom constructor has several strings and a few dates for parameters but no number types. Both the types and the number of parameters mismatch and your object fails.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50773648/create-a-collection-of-objects-from-data-in-a-text-file

Comment: I'm using VB 2015. Okay I think I understand. If I were to change the dates to doubles would that help?  Do you have to have an even number of parameters in a custom constructor?  I'm thinking of just getting rid of the duedate and the daterented.

Comment: I would change the year published to an integer. It is just a four digit number that you may want to sort someday. Leave the dates as dates; again you may want to sort. The number of parameters you pass to the constructor must match the number of parameters you have listed in the constructor. There are such things as Optional Parameters but let's save that for another day.

Comment: BTW, the reason you got the funny numbers in you DataGridView is the DataGridView1.DataMember defaults to the first Public Property of the type it is bound to which in the case of System.String, is the Length.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create a collection of objects from data in a text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50773648/create-a-collection-of-objects-from-data-in-a-text-file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok Sydney, let's get this thing working!

1. Either you have seriously ignored your studies or your instructor
   has left you to flounder; in which case you should notify your
   college that you are not getting what you are paying for.
2. Your object contains too much data. You need a book object, a customer object and a rental object. Suppose the library director
   wants a list of all your clients. In your model you would have each
   client listed many times and it would be a mess to get the director
   his list.
3. Use Automatic Properties if you can. I think they are available in VS 2015. You only need to write Public Property Title as String
   and the wonderful vb compiler will write the get, set, and the
   private field for you in the Itermedite Language code. (You won't
   see it in your source code but it is there)
4. Now your text file. One line per book. Each property of the book should be separated by a character that does not appear elsewhere in
   the file. How about the pipe character (|) (the uppercase backslash)
   So a line in your file would look like... 1|Innoncent Injustice(A
   Chance Reddick Thriller Book 1)|David Archer|B07D6442LM|2018 Notice
   I have added another field, the BookID
5. I haven't included the default constructor (the one with no parameters). This forces any code creating a book object to provide
   values for all parameters even if it is only "".

```vb
Public Class Book
    Public Property BookID As Integer
    Public Property Title As String
    Public Property Author As String
    Public Property ISBN As String
    Public Property YearPublished As Integer
    Public Sub New(id As Integer, bTitle As String, bAuthor As String, bISBN As String, bPublished As Integer)
        BookID = id
        Title = bTitle
        Author = bAuthor
        ISBN = bISBN
        YearPublished = bPublished
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class Project1Data
    Private lstBooks As New List(Of Book)
    Private Sub Project1Data_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim textfile As String
        OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog()
        textfile = OpenFileDialog1.FileName
        Dim lines() As String = IO.File.ReadAllLines(textfile)

        For Each line As String In lines
            Dim fields() As String = line.Split("|"c) 'the little c after "|" indicates that this is a char
            'String.Split takes a char
            Dim b As New Book(CInt(fields(0)), fields(1), fields(2), fields(3), CInt(fields(4)))
            lstBooks.Add(b)
        Next
        DataGridView1.DataSource = lstBooks
    End Sub
End Class
```